# Kafka Topic same key going to different partitions (in failure scenarios)

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

We are using Kafka Topics along with KSQL to store some records for our purposes.
What we have noticed is that when failures occur (example - out of memory, persistent volume issues) a specific message key can go in different partitions (example - it was going in partition 2, but after the failure it starts going into partition 3).
Anyone experienced something similar? Is there a way to mitigate this?